# Multiple jquery dialogue for each click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have gridview where i am editing row in a separate popup window by using a jquery ui dialogue.My question is Can we have a seperate window for each row edit in gridview.I am using a usercontrol for adding data and same user control is used in popup window by using different `DIV`

i am posting code what i have done
This is where i am entering data in to database,`DIV is addID` user control is `TestUserControl`

```
<div id="addID" class="divTable">
        <div class="divRow">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <uc1:TestUserControl runat="server" ID="idAdd" />
                    <div>
</div>
```

This is the `div` ,`idMain` responsible for editing which i will popup in jquery dialgue

```
 <div id="idMain" style="display: none; background-color: #EEEEEE" class="divTable">
            <div class="divRow"> 
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlEdit" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="iForm" class="divRow">                                                 
                            <div class="divRow">
                                <uc1:TestUserControl runat="server" ID="IdUserControl" />
                                <div>
```

following is the jquery i am using to popup

```
function showIdDetails(divobj, pagetitle, width, height) {
    $("#" + divobj)
          .dialog({
              open: function () {
                  $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error");
              },
              title: pagetitle,
              appendTo: "form",
              modal: false,
              draggable: true,
              resizable: true,
              width: width
          })
```

Finally i will call `showIdDetails` function in `gridview row command`  as like shown below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", "showIdDetails('idMain','ID DETAILS','600','400');", true);
```

As of now what is happening is foreach edit click i am popping up single window which contains the row i clicked.And what i want is foreach click i want to popup seperate window contains corresponding row,how to do it?

Comment: can you show what you have done??Some code will give a clear understanding about your problem.

Comment: i will post what i have done

Comment: @Farhad Rakib i posted my code